# How to create multi-line inside the bracket

Tags: brackets

something like this: How to create mulitl-line inside the bracket

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `\parbox`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand*{\bracketedtext}[2][21mm]{%
    \mathord{%
        \color{cyan}
        \left[ \parbox{#1}{\color{black}\raggedright#2} \right]
        \normalcolor
    }%
}
\begin{document}
\[
\bracketedtext{the number of rabbit pairs alive at the end of month \(k\)}
=
\bracketedtext{the number of rabbit pairs alive at the end of month \(k-1\)}
+
\bracketedtext{the number of rabbit pairs born at the end of month \(k\)}
\]
\end{document}
```